# MTLTexture only showing one color of the image

Tags: ios, swift, metal, metalkit

I was following raywenderlich's Metal tutorial, but got stuck rendering a texture on a plane, it seems to be showing only one color of the image, not the entire image. I'm running on an iPad iOS 12.3.

Here's a repo for the project: https://github.com/TheJoseph-Dev/MyMetalProgram

May anyone help me?

Comment: Your project will build, but it will not run because it is missing the Main.xib file.  Adding one to the project and configuring the view controller lets the application build and run. But it still doesn't render.  All in all it looks like you need to spend some more time studying iOS development and the tutorial you were trying to follow.

Comment: @ScottThompson I downloaded the project again and it works without the Main.xib file. I like to develop programmatically, so I deleted the Main.xib file and set everything up in AppDelegate and SceneDelegate.

Comment: I had to go into the plist settings and remove the reference to "Main" in the scenes array in the those settings.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Renderer` implementation, set a breakpoint on the line that reads:

```
private lazy var device = metalView.device
```

And run your code.

At the point in which this line is executed, the `metalView` exists, but the `device` on that metalView is nil.  Similar problems can be seen for the other `lazy` properties of the renderer.

You may wish to use a less complex property style as it appears the properties are not being collected when the view is in the state you expect.  I suspect that the view will not create resources like its `device` until it is attached to a window which will happen after `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Hmm, I tried removing all the`lazy` properties in the renderer and setting their values before `super.init()`, but I ended up in the same problem. However, even with the `lazy` properties, the device could not be nil, otherwise the app would just crash. The weirdest thing is that I can render a multicolored rectangle when the texture is `nil`, but can't render the texture.